# Using command prompt batch files to automatically rename duplicate files

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I have batch file that generates one file `*.txt` that I use for review some details about installation process of a software, all good BUT how can I generate a new `*.txt` file on the same location with a different name or number?

For example: 
If folder `C:\Users\John\Documents` contains a file named `ProgramLog.txt` I need that the name of a new change to `*.txt` eg. `Programlog1.txt` and so on (leaving the `ProgramLog.txt` in the same location)

Sorry here is my batch:

```
msiexec /i "C:\Windows\System32\John.msi" /passive /log c:\Programlog.txt
```

---

I added this, renames and add an extra character (number one) but overwrites the file:-(

```
@ECHO Off &SETLOCAL 
FOR %%a IN (*.txt) DO CALL:processFile "%%~a" 
goto:eof 

:processFile 
SETLOCAL 
:loop 
SET /a fileCounter+=1 
SET "fileName=%~n1%filecounter%%~x1" 
IF EXIST "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%fileName%" GOTO:loop 
ECHO MOVE "%~1" "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%fileName%" 
ENDLOCAL 
goto:eof
```

Comment: How are the current files being generated? changing the output in batch is just `> filename`

Comment: Why don't you supply the relevant part of your batch file that makes the file, and then someone can amend it to rename the file if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to keep the first file named `ProgramLog.txt`? 
This would be simpler if you would just rename the first file to `ProgramLog1.txt`,
the second one to `ProgramLog2.txt`, etc.  Because saying

```
msiexec … /log c:\ProgramLog.txt
```

is going to overwrite an existing file called `ProgramLog.txt`.

If you must do it this way, change the `msiexec` command to

```
msiexec … /log c:\temp.txt
```

and then rename `temp.txt` to `ProgramLog.txt` the first time, `ProgramLog1.txt` the second time, `ProgramLog2.txt` the third time, etc.  Alternatively, do your original command:

```
msiexec … /log c:\ProgramLog.txt
```

the first time (when `ProgramLog.txt` doesn’t exist),
and on all subsequent runs create `temp.txt` and rename it.